# Finding $N^3$ for a matrix N

Tags: matrices

> Let N be defined as follows:
>
> $$ N\in \{ A \in Mat(n\,\times n;\ K):(i\ge j \Rightarrow a_{ij}=0)\ \text{and}\ (k<l\Rightarrow a_{kl}=1) \}. $$
>
> Find $N^3.$

After couple of tries with fixed values of $n$, I led to believe $N^3$ is the $0$ matrix.

I even have trouble finding (formally) $N^2$. Given that the definition for matrix multiplication is

$$\sum_{k=1}^na_{ik}a_{kj}$$ All I could arrive at is that for a term not to be $0$, $i<k<j$. But that is about it.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Your belief is wrong. For $n = 4$ you have $N^3$ is identically zero, except for entry $a_{14} = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $N$ being of the form $$N=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1&1&\cdots&1&1\\0&0&1&1&1\cdots&1&1\\0&0&0&1&1\cdots&1&1\\\\0&0&0&0&0\cdots&1&1\\0&0&0&0&0\cdots&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0\cdots&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
we can consider $N$ as representing a linear operator $T$ with respect to the canonical basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,\cdots, e_n\}$ so we have
$$\begin{array}TT(e_1)=0\\T(e_2)=e_1\\T(e_3)=e_1+e_2\\T(e_4)=e_1+e_2+e_3\\T(e_5)=e_1+e_2+e_3+e_4\\........................\\........................\\T(e_n)=e_1+e_2+e_3+\cdots+e_{n-1}\end{array}$$ Notice that
$$\begin{array}TT(e_1)=0\\T(e_2)=e_1\\T(e_3)=T(e_2)+e_2\\T(e_4)=T(e_3)+e_3\\T(e_5)=T(e_4)+e_4\\........................\\........................\\T(e_n)=T(e_{n-1})+e_{n-1}\end{array}$$
It follows $$\begin{array}TT^2(e_1)=0\\T^2(e_2)=0\\T^2(e_3)=e_1\\T^2(e_4)=2e_1+e_2\\T^2(e_5)=3e_1+2e_2+e_3\\T^2(e_6)=4e_1+3e_2+2e_3+e_4\\T^2(e_7)=5e_1+4e_2+3e_3+2e_4+e_5\\........................\\........................\\T^2(e_n)=(n-2)e_1+(n-3)e_2+(n-4)e_3+\cdots+3e_{n-4}+2e_{n-3}+e_{n-2}\end{array}$$ Taking now $T^3$ we have
$$\begin{array}TT^3(e_1)=0\\T^3(e_2)=0\\T^3(e_3)=0\\T^3(e_4)=e_1\\T^3(e_5)=3e_1+e_2\\T^3(e_6)=6e_1+3e_2+e_3\\T^3(e_7)=10e_1+6e_2+3e_3+e_4\\T^3(e_8)=15e_1+10e_2+6e_3+3e_4+e_5\\........................\\........................\\T^3(e_n)=(\sum_{k=1}^{n-3}k)e_1+(\sum_{k=1}^{n-4}k)e_2+(\sum_{k=1}^{n-5}k)e_3+\cdots+e_{n-3}\end{array}$$ Consequently we get 
$$N^3=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0&1&3&6&10&15&21&28&36&...\\0&0&0&0&1&3&6&10&15&21&28&...\\0&0&0&0&0&1&3&6&10&15&21&...\\0&0&0&0&0&0&1&3&6&10&15&...\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&3&6&10&...\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&3&6&...\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&3&...\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&...\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&...\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&...\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&…\\&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&...\\.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&.&...\end{bmatrix}\qquad(*)$$

We have completely written the matrix of order $11$ (*which implicitely gives the answer for $1\le n\le 11$*). For the matrix $N$ of order $n$ the matrix $N^3$ is determined by its first row which is defined as follows:
$$\begin{cases}a_{1j}=0\text{ for } j=1,2,3\\ a_{1j}=1+2+3+\cdots+j=\dfrac{(j-3)(j-2)}{2}\text{ for } 4\le j\le n\end{cases}$$

The other rows follow the pattern showed above by $(*)$ which is straightforwardly determined by the first row.

NOTE.- Successive square submatrices in $(*)$ starting from $a_{11}$ till $a_{nn}$ give the answers for successive values of $n$. For $n=2$ and $n=3$ one has $N^3=0$ but for $n = 4$ we verify Daniel's comment above. For greater values of the order $n$ the corresponding matrix acquires greater and greater values.

Answer (score 3):

$(N^3)_{ij}$ is the number of pairs of integers $(k,\ell)$ such that $i < k < \ell < j$.

Comment: Seeing as my answer would have this exact text in its last sentence, I'll confine the difference to a comment: $N$ can be understood as the adjacency matrix of a directed graph with vertex set $\{ 1,2,\dots,n \}$ where there is an edge from $i$ to $j$ if and only if $i<j$. Therefore $(N^k)_{ij}$ is the number of paths from $i$ to $j$ of length $k$.